# Is there an algebraic treatment of ragged tensors?

Tags: tensors, multilinear-algebra

A [ragged tensor](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/ragged_tensor) in certain machine learning libraries is a multidimensional array with a non-rectangular shape. However, this is within a context where tensors are multidimensional arrays. In pure mathematics, a tensor is a multilinear object with algebraic properties. Has there been any pure mathematical work on taking ragged tensors in the ML context and finding a similar algebraic structure for them?

**Addendum**
Ragged tensors in ML are useful when features exist that do not have a consistent shape. From the tensorflow documentation:

> Your data comes in many shapes; your tensors should too. Ragged tensors are the TensorFlow equivalent of nested variable-length lists. They make it easy to store and process data with non-uniform shapes, including:

> - Variable-length features, such as the set of actors in a movie.
> - Batches of variable-length sequential inputs, such as sentences or video clips.
> - Hierarchical inputs, such as text documents that are subdivided into sections, paragraphs, sentences, and words.
> - Individual fields in structured inputs, such as protocol buffers.

Comment: What do ragged tensors describe in ML?